# Wildcard ssl installed for my subdomain with magento installation is not working

Tags: php, magento, ssl

I have a main domain with Magento installation.Now I have created a subdomain under this account with same document root ( Both my main domain and subdomain using same document root ). To secure my site I have bought a wildcard ssl certificate, my hosting provider installed it successfully, however at the product  checkout time the browser showing the site is not secured. It showing self-signed ssl warning ( not secure ). My magento instance using 2 websites each with one store-view. If I call the subdomain ex: https://www.us.domain.com/ it show ssl self signed warning. 
I have asked it about my hosting provider then they replied, the ssl installation is successful for the subdomain us.domain.com to confirm this they have provided sslchecker url. Can somebody help me on this.

Comment: is in main domain, checkout page is secure ?

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed it myself. In the shop admin, under System > Configuration > Web for "view name" . changed the base URL as follows.

http://www.us.bboheme.com/

https://www.us.domain.com/

to:

http://us.domain.com/

https://us.domain.com/

I think wild card ssl will not work for https://www.us.domain (*.*.domain.com ) but it will work for https://us.domain.com